# how can i change content placeholder on button click?

Tags: asp.net, placeholder, buttonclick

when i debugging i get a error message showing " Object reference not set to an instance of an object" .

here is my code...............

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ContentPlaceHolder cph1 = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
    ContentPlaceHolder cph2 = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder2");
    cph1.Visible = true;
    cph2.Visible = false;
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ContentPlaceHolder cph1 = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
    ContentPlaceHolder cph2 = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder2");
    cph1.Visible = true;
    cph2.Visible = false;

    String ltype=DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    momconnect obj = new momconnect();
    obj.getconnect();
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select Levdef_id from Tbl_leave_define where Levtype='"+ltype+"'", obj.conn);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();
    Session["defid"]=dr["Levdef_id"].ToString();
    dr.Close();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_leave_request", obj.conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@flag", 1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Staff_id", Session["staffid"].ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Levtype",ltype);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason",TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Num", TextBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Frmdate", TextBox3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Todate",TextBox4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Levdef_id", Session["defid"].ToString());
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cph1.Visible = false;
    cph2.Visible = true;
    Label1.Text = "Leave request sent. Wait for approval";



}
```

Comment: and error is on line number?

Comment: In  which line? AVOID sting concatenation in your sql statement. Use params

Comment: @user3463333 please debug the code and check where u are getting the error

Comment: the error is on line no:6  [cph2.Visible = false;]

Comment: Can you post the designer code for the maser page also, that would help in identifying the problem.